# Placing JavaScript ad tag on different location in page

Tags: javascript, document.write

I have a page, that calls "first.js" script. This script ads to  a call to "second.js" script:

**first.js:**

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'second.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script)
```

now, if I put in second.js alert("test"), I will see a good alert.
However, if I put in second.js document.write("something"), I will not get that document.write.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is being loaded into the `head`, typically where none of the elements are rendered in the browser's viewport.

If this were to run too, it would clear the page if had started to render as `document.write()` implicitly calls `document.open()` first.